# Why is the bill from my health care provider sometimes called a "factura"?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

I've seen it on several healthcare-related invoices that I've received over the years. I'm assuming it's some kind of "legacy" word used in the healthcare industry. But what is this strange word "factura"? Why not "invoice" or "bill"?

Comment: Um... Factura is Spanish.

Comment: In Czech, "faktura" is the same as bill...so maybe the company providing you health care is originally not from English speaking country? Provided the one you live in is, of course.

Comment: Is the rest of the bill in Spanish? Because RK01 is correct--*factura* is Spanish for "bill."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

factura is Spanish for invoice.

I imagine you live in an area where there are many Spanish speakers.